# joblib package - why is Parallel() giving *incorrect* output? Changing n_jobs=1 to n_jobs=3 changes the output

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I emphasized "incorrect" because the problem isn't that Parallel() is giving a slower or same-speed run as my code, it's that the output result is different.

I am working in Google Colab, and I am trying to parallelize a for-loop (specifically, I'm trying to parallelize the outer loop of a nested cross-validation loop, if that helps).

Basically, the code is running an outer for-loop which is supposed to shift a window along a data table, where models are trained with different parameters (inner for loop), best parameters determined, and then one model is trained on all the "preceding" data and tested on an untouched fold of the data.

Here is roughly my code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def NestedCV(outer):   
  traindataforthisiteration = data[0:(1000+outer*500),:]
  testdataforthisiteration = data[(1000+outer*500):(1000+(outer+1)*500),:]
  bestresult = 0
  bestparam = 0
  paramoptions = [1,2,3]
  for i in paramoptions:
    # Testing every parameter option, recording result, updating "bestparam" and "bestresult"
    # if better result is encountered on each iteration i
    innertrain = traindataforthisiteration[0:(1000+outer*500)/2,:]
    innertest = traindataforthisiteration[(1000+outer*500)/2:(1000+outer*500),:]
    innermodel = model(i).fit(innertrain)
    # Next line runs trained model on innertest, obtaining some performance metric as output
    performance = accuracy(model.predict(innertest))
    if performance > bestresult:
       bestresult = performance
       bestparam = i

  finalmodel = model(bestparam).fit(traindataforthisiteration)
  results = finalmodel.predict(testdataforthisiteration)

  return results, bestparam
```

I wanted to parallelize this for-loop (so, instead of running the 3 outer folds sequentially, I would run them all at the same time since they are independent of one another, because parameters are selected for each fold individually).

Here is what I did to parallelize:

```
inputs = range(3)
results = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(NestedCV)(i) for i in inputs)
```

Now here's what I don't understand. When I run this code, the output is different (and presumably wrong) compared to when I run the code sequentially or ANY other way. Here are the ways I have tried running the code:

1. Copy and paste the code from inside the "def NestedCV" and just running it straight, without a function. Just setting "outer=0" and running the code.
2. Run "NestedCV(0)", "NestedCV(1)" and "NestedCV(2)" separately
3. Run "inputs = range(3)" and then "results = Parallel(***n_jobs=1***)(delayed(NestedCV)(i) for i in inputs)" . Notice, I changed n_jobs=1, so presumably it's not REALLY being run in parallel anymore?

All of the above gave the same result, and that result was different than when I run "results = Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(NestedCV)(i) for i in inputs)".

I would greatly appreciate any insight as to what is going on here and what my mistake is.

EDIT: I'm not a frequent user of Google Colab, and I don't often run things in parallel (I literally grabbed that Parallel(n_jobs=3)(delayed(... code from a blog). That's to say, the mistake is probably something super basic on my part, but I cannot figure out what it could possibly be. I thought "maybe the loop iterations are somehow dependent on each other, so running in parallel doesn't work" but then running "NestedCV(n)" in random orders should give inconsistent result, right? But it doesn't..

EDIT 2: My function has multiple outputs. Is this relevant? Can I somehow be capturing the output incorrectly? I changed my func to reflect the multiple outputs.

EDIT 3: In case it helps, here is my actual code (still a bit simplified). It's for a Reinforcement Learning agent, coded using Stable-Baselines3.

```
def NestedCV(outer):
  lrparams = [0.0003, 0.0001]
  batchsizes = [256]
  gammaoptions = [0.9]
  starttimestep = 250000
  increment = 100000
  # Remember that it's in range(inctimes), where timesteps=starttimestep when inctime==0
  inctimes = 1

  outertrainltc = ltctrain.iloc[0:(outercvstart+outer*outerfoldsize),:]
  outertrainpriceltc = ltcpricestrain[0:(outercvstart+outer*outerfoldsize)]

  outertest = train.iloc[((outercvstart+outer*outerfoldsize)+1):(outercvstart+(outer+1)*outerfoldsize),:]
  outertestprice = pricestrain[((outercvstart+outer*outerfoldsize)+1):(outercvstart+(outer+1)*outerfoldsize)]

  bestlr = 0
  bestf = 0
  bestr = 0
  bestg = 0
  bestrew = -np.inf
  for lr in lrparams:
    for r in batchsizes:
      for g in gammaoptions:
        innerres1 = []
        innerres2 = []
        for inner in range(2):
          lastind = (len(outertrain.index)-3*innerfoldsize+inner*innerfoldsize)
          
          # Train first stage (rule learning stage) of model
          env = StockPredEnv(df1=outertrainltc.iloc[0:lastind,:], priceseries1=list(outertrainpriceltc[0:lastind]),  
                      episodelen= 2225,
                  totaltimesteps=starttimestep)
          
          env = ActionMasker(env, mask_fn)

          model = MaskablePPO(MaskableActorCriticPolicy, env, verbose=0, learning_rate=lr, gamma=g, batch_size=r, seed=10)

          for rep in range(inctimes):
            if rep==0:
              model.learn(starttimestep)
            else:
              model.learn(increment)
            
            # Testing out on test data
            # Changing env to be based on test data
            env = StockPredEnv(df1=outertrainltc.iloc[lastind:(lastind+innerfoldsize),:],
                    priceseries1=list(outertrainpriceltc[lastind:(lastind+innerfoldsize)])
                    episodelen= len(list(outertrainprice[lastind:(lastind+innerfoldsize)]))-1, 
                    totaltimesteps=starttimestep+rep*increment)
            env = ActionMasker(env, mask_fn)

            obs = env.reset().astype('float')
            done = False
            score = 0
            while not done:
              action_masks = get_action_masks(env)
              action, _ = model.predict(obs, action_masks=action_masks, deterministic=True)
              obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action[0])
              score += reward

            if inner==0:
              innerres1.append(score)
            else:
              innerres2.append(score)
        
        # Calculating mean score for each timestep
        meanscores = []
        for m in range(len(innerres1)):
          meanscores.append(np.mean([innerres1[m], innerres2[m]]))

        # Calculating best result and corresponding timesteps
        topmean = -np.inf
        toptimesteps = 0
        for m in range(len(meanscores)):
          if meanscores[m] > topmean:
            topmean = meanscores[m]
            toptimesteps = starttimestep + m*increment

        # Checking result vs. previous results, recording if hyperparams are better
        if topmean > bestrew:
          bestrew = topmean
          bestlr = lr
          bestf = toptimesteps
          bestr = r
          bestg = g
  # Recording best params
  bestparams = (bestlr, bestf, bestr, bestg)
  cvbestrew = bestrew

  # Training model on all innner data to run on outer test fold
  # Train first stage (rule learning stage) of model
  env = StockPredEnv(df1=outertrainltc,
                    priceseries1=list(outertrainpriceltc),  
                    episodelen= 2225, 
                    totaltimesteps=bestf)
  
  env = ActionMasker(env, mask_fn)

  model = MaskablePPO(MaskableActorCriticPolicy, env, verbose=0, 
learning_rate=bestlr, gamma=bestg, batch_size=bestr, seed=10)
  model.learn(bestf)
  
  # Testing out on test data
  # Changing env to include test data 
  env = StockPredEnv(df1=outertrainltc,
                    priceseries1=list(outertrainpriceltc), 
                    episodelen= len(list(outertestprice))-1, 
                    totaltimesteps=len(list(outertestprice)))
  env = ActionMasker(env, mask_fn)

  lastepisodeactions = []

  obs = env.reset().astype('float')
  done = False
  score = 0
  while not done:
    action_masks = get_action_masks(env)
    action, _ = model.predict(obs, action_masks=action_masks, 
deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action[0])
    score += reward
    lastepisodeactions.append(action)

  outerfoldrew = score
  tradeactions = lastepisodeactions
  return bestparams, outerfoldrew, tradeactions
```

EDIT 4: I tried running 3 instances of the function in parallel with the exact same input. And interestingly, the **outputs were all exactly the same****, but still different than when I run it sequentially**. This suggests that the problem isn't a "race condition", right? Otherwise the 3 parallelized outputs would all be different? What could this mean?

Comment: you didn't show original code - so we can't check if you use`Parallel` in correct way. You said you train one model but `Parallel` creates three separated models and I don't see where you train one model.

Comment: @furas I added in some code to represent what goes on in the inner for-loop. Does that make things more clear? Thank you for taking the time to clarify.

Comment: @furas I'm hesitant to post my actual code because it's kinda complicated and long, I thought maybe the issue is already present in my simplified representation.

Comment: @furas I went ahead and added my actual code at the bottom.

Comment: It's not clear with only this section of the code, but are the return values used to update the ltctrain or outer* data when the function is complete?  In that case, I would expect the sequential runs to give different results than the parallel run, because in the parallel case they would all be starting with the same initial data, where the sequential run would be using different starting data on each iteration.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety No, they aren't used to update that data . The data is defined outside of the loop and not modified (I even tried putting it IN the loop, and still same problem). I added an EDIT 4, would you mind taking a look? It might be an important piece of info.